WSL does not launch properly anymore in VSCode
I can open VSCode WSL in a new window but once it's opened i can't do anything because i cannot access any folder.
I have made a restoration to a previous windows update (dating 27 september 2024) due to a bug concerning my touchpad and since then i had several bugs including this one.
VScode with WSL worked fine until here and the folder i was working on is still on WSL desktop, named PyfDownloadTool. I can still open WSL using my terminal and use commands there so the problem is not WSL related directly.
When i try to open a folder, i have a warning saying this :

File system provider for vscode-remote://wsl%2Bubuntu/home/daeltam/python/PyfDownloadTool is not available.

If I try to double click the folder preview shown on the folder's list, i have this error :

Unable to solve resource : vscode-remote://wsl%2Ubuntu/home/daeltam/python/PyfDownloadTool

And if i try to configure my settings to exist trusted mode (as presented on the welcome page), i have this error :

The editor could not be opened due to an unexpected error: No remote extension installed to resolve wsl.

I have tried uninstalling and installing back the Windows VSCode WSL extension, realoading the extentions but didn't work.
I restarted my laptop, didn't worked neither.
Only thing strange I see is that i don't have any vscode folder created in the python folder for WSL
I see in the bottom right corner that it's written Disconnected from WSL even if it says in the upper bar that I do am in Ubuntu WSL
Last tests : i managed to Close remote connexion but now i can't log back in WSL, when i click on the option nothing happens, no error message.
Typing code in the work forder using the WSL terminal connexion managed to open VScode but still the same warning in the bottom left :

:Warning Logo: Disconnected from WSL : Ubuntu

